# AFNetworking simple HTTP request

Tags: objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

I am using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) in my project and I simply need to check if a URL is successful (status 2xx).

I tried

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2check];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
    JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            NSLog(@"Ok %@", JSON);
        }
    }
    failure:nil
];
[operation start];
```

But as I'm not awaiting JSON especially, I was expecting to use something like

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFHTTPRequestOperation
    HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest: success: failure:];
```

But this does not exist (I don't know why), so I used

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
    initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:...]
```

Isn't there simpler ?

How would you do this simple URL check with AFNetworking ?

Comment: if this question isn't complete and submitted by error, why you dont edit or delete it?

Comment: Can I know the potential reason(s) of any downvote please ?

Comment: undone downvote after edit

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up with

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2check];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                     initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation
                                           , id responseObject) {
        // code
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // code
    }
];
[operation start];
```

Feel free to add a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

You just could instantiate a AFHTTPClient object with the base URL and call `getPath:parameters:success:failure:` on it.

[from the docs:](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/getPath%3aparameters%3asuccess%3afailure%3a)

> Creates an AFHTTPRequestOperation with a GET request, and enqueues it to the HTTP client’s operation queue.

Comment: Could you give me an example ? I can't make it work. I'm quite new to xcode actually

Comment: Post your attempt in ur question, and I'll tell u what is wrong. Btw: Xcode is neither a language or a framework. It is just an editor.

Comment: You are right, I meant objective-c. I have put my working solution as answer. If you get simpler, feel free to put it, I'll surely vote up :)

Comment: sure it gets simpler: use `[aClient getPath: parameters: success: failure: ]` as I suggested in the answer already.